# Como usar una funcion de un controlador en otro controlador ANGUALRJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Estoy haciendo un `REST` donde intento llamar en una función, una función de otro controlador, pero con `$parent` no me muestra en consola la función ni con el `$scope`, la función que intento llamar es esta  `$scope.getInsuranceRequests();`:

```
$scope.example = function() {
    $http.get(root + 'ruta/url', {
            params: id
        }).then(function(res) {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                Dialogs.infoToast("Correo enviado correctamente");              
                $scope.getInsuranceRequests();
            }
        }
}
```

Estoy intentando con esto

```
angular.extend(this, $controller('OtroControladorQueTieneLafuncionQueNecesito', {
       $scope: $scope 
    }));
```

Answer (score 3):

No deberías de inicializar un controlador solo para obtener la referencia a una función, ya que estarías haciendo demasiado trabajo e inicializando objetos innecesarios.

Engloba tu función en un `service` e inyéctalo en todos los controladores que necesites. Por ejemplo:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.service("insuranceService",function(){
  this.getInsuranceRequests = function(){
    console.log("obteniendo los insurrance");
  }
  
})
.controller("ctrl1",function($scope, insuranceService)
{
   $scope.mostrarValor = function() {
    insuranceService.getInsuranceRequests()
   }
})
.controller("ctrl2",function($scope, insuranceService)
{
   $scope.mostrarValor = function() {
    insuranceService.getInsuranceRequests()
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" >
  <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
    <button ng-click="mostrarValor()">Mostrar valor</button>
  </div>
   <div ng-controller="ctrl2">
    <button ng-click="mostrarValor()">Mostrar valor</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok muchas gracias @Einer eres el mejor

Comment: es que ando usando angular-material y uso $mdDialog e intecto inyectar controlador pero no veo como....

Comment: Debiste de mencionar ese detalle en tu pregunta. Editala e intenta explicar que es lo que te pasa agregando solo el codigo relevante a la pregunta para poder ayudarte.